# quiz template in unity issue

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

i've done this unity project following a youtube tutorial.
but i is not working can you figure out the problem??
ok so the first code is

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AnswerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isCorrect = false;
    public QuizManager quizManager;

    public Color startc;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        startc = GetComponent<Image>().color;
    }

    public void Answer()
    {
        if (isCorrect)
        {
            GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
            Debug.Log("Correct Answer");
            quizManager.correct();
        }
        else
        {
            GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
            Debug.Log("Wrong Answer");
            quizManager.wrong();
        }
    }

}
```

and the second is   this one it is a little script

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[System.Serializable]

public class QuestionAndANWSER 
{
    public Image[] Question;
    public string[] Answers;
    public int CorrectAnswer;
}
```

the third is this one the biggest script:)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class QuizManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<QuestionAndANWSER> Qna;
    public GameObject[] options;
    public int currentQuestion;

    public GameObject QuizPanel;
    public GameObject GOPanel;
    

    public Text  QuestionTxt;
    public Text ScoreTxt;

    int totalQuestions = 0;
    public int score;
    

    private void Start()
    {
       
        totalQuestions = Qna.Count;
        GOPanel.SetActive(false);
        generateQuestion();
        
    }
    public void retry()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }

    public  void GameOver()
    {
        QuizPanel.SetActive(false);
        GOPanel.SetActive(true);
        ScoreTxt.text = score +"/"+ totalQuestions;
    }
    public void correct()
    {
        score += 1;
        Qna.RemoveAt(currentQuestion);
        StartCoroutine(WaitforNext());
    }

    public void wrong()
    {
       
        Qna.RemoveAt(currentQuestion);
        StartCoroutine(WaitforNext());
    }
    IEnumerator WaitforNext()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        generateQuestion();
    }
    void SetAnswer()
    {
        for (int i= 0; i < options.Length; i++)
        {
            options[i].GetComponent<Image>().color = options[i].GetComponent<AnswerScript>().startc;
            options[i].GetComponent<AnswerScript>().isCorrect = false;
            options[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = Qna[currentQuestion].Answers[i];

            if(Qna[currentQuestion].CorrectAnswer == i + 1)
            {
                options[i].GetComponent<AnswerScript>().isCorrect = true;
            }
        }
    }
    void generateQuestion()
    {
        if(Qna.Count > 0)
        {
            currentQuestion = Random.Range(0, Qna.Count);

            QuestionTxt.text = Qna[currentQuestion].Question;
            SetAnswer();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("out of questions");
            GameOver();
        }
        

        
    }
}
```

it is a quiz template but i doesn't work. does anyone know how to fix that?
i am a begginer in learning c#

Comment: "it doesn't work." I have no idea what that means. It doesn't compile, or it doesn't show a question, or something else?

Comment: it has an error saying "cannot implicity convert type unityEngine.ui.image[] to string

Comment: ....and which script does it tell you that error is located in? And on which line number? And which line of the snippets you've provided is that?

Comment: quiz manager script the biggest one and on the line 81 and the error code is CS0029

Answer (score 0):

When you define a question and answer:

```
public class QuestionAndANWSER 
{
    public Image[] Question;
    public string[] Answers;
    public int CorrectAnswer;
}
```

you are storing questions as IMAGES. Later, in `generateQuestion()`, you're trying to use the questions as TEXT:

```
void generateQuestion()
{
    // ...
        QuestionTxt.text = Qna[currentQuestion].Question;
    // ...
}
```

You have to be consistent in how you're handling the questions. You either need to change the `QuizManager` to use an image for the `QuestionTxt` or you need to change `QuestionAndANSWER` to use text for the `Question`.

Comment: I appreciate your work very much. but how can i change the QuizManager to use an image for the QuestionTxt?

Comment: @MichaelGerges - Use a [UnityEngine.UI.Image](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.Image.html) instead of a `UnityEngine.UI.Text`.